# Do npm vulnerabilities matter for front ends?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, npm, single-page-application

When running the command 'npm install' or 'npm audit', I usually receive notices of package vulnerabilities. In my case, I'm only using npm packages for a Javascript client that I send to my users as an SPA (single page application).

Are there ever security vulnerabilities I should be aware of that affect UI/UX implementations of npm, or are these messages exclusively for when npm packages are used on node servers?

Here is an example of when I run 'npm audit':

[image: An example of running the command 'npm audit']

Comment: Yes, they do matter sometimes. You just have to read the advisory and figure out whether it applies to how you’re using it.

Comment: DoS and code injections can be quite serious. You should evaluate and check if those are acceptible risks - it might be that the vulnerability exists in a specific parts of the API you don't use or perhaps in some specific usages that you don't have in your code. Or you might just decide it's extremely unlikely that it will ever come up. Still, they *are* vulnerabilities and simply turning a blind eye to them is probably bad.

Comment: I thought DoS would only be an issue if the node package was being used on the backend though. So essentially, these messages could include vulnerabilities for front-end implementations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can matter.

People have attempted to sneak malware via front-end code before. So far it has been through infecting ad servers or something similar like an API that uses JSONP. But it could be done via infecting modules on npm.

There is a fairly [famous case of someone inserting code to steal Bitcoin private keys](https://www.zdnet.com/article/hacker-backdoors-popular-javascript-library-to-steal-bitcoin-funds/) (allowing them to spend other people's Bitcoins) by modifying the code for the [EventStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-stream) module. It was a fairly subtle and long operation involving the hacker first volunteering bug fixes then helping out maintaining the library then finally requesting to become the lead maintainer.

EventStream is a node.js only module so it isn't a front-end thing. But the possibility exists for someone to silently add code to modify things like `Math.random` or `window.fetch` to secretly alter your logic or snoop on your communications.

If the vulnerability gets shipped to browser code you should investigate what it is and if it matters to your application.

If the vulnerability only affect developer tooling (for example a css pre-processor or a build system like `gulp`) then it doesn't matter because it only gets executed when you build or debug your project.

Comment: I suppose it can also matter if (for some reason) you ever upload your `node_modules` folder to a publicly accessible folder by mistake.