# Why is npm audit fix force not dealing with my react app vulnerabilities?

Tags: reactjs, npm, frontend, npx

I have been trying to create a react app using npx.
-At first it said  " create-react-app " is no longer supported (problem solved I managed to generate an operating react app with a template).
-Then it started throwing warning (deprecated files) I managed to fix some of them but not all of them.

- The app was created but with 6 high sevirity vulnerabilities.
- I ran an audit fix --force it gave me 66 vulnerabilities. I ran the npm audit fix -force again it gave me the old 6 vulnerabilities.

My question is should I use the react app even with the high severity vulnerabilities or not use the react app because it will be used by my teammates as well.

Here is an overview in my terminal:
[vulnerabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23602.jpg)

Comment: Honestly, I’d dig into NPM audit. It’s a pretty broken and generally useless system. Dan Abramov has a good little article about this too.

Comment: Why would `npx create-react-app app-name` not be supported? Can you give the exact command you typed and the error that you get? And to know if your template is wrong, we'd need to know what template you used? If it's an old deprecated template you might get warnings about it...

Comment: I typed the exact command you typed and it said it is no longer supported but then I used npx create-react-app@latest app-name and it installed the lastest create-react-app and it no longer showed.

Comment: The command not working means you have a globally installed version of CRA, which was being used. This isn't recommended. Your workaround is fine though.

Comment: npm vulnerabilities are common. Don't get hung up on that. Fix what you can.

Comment: Alright, thank you all so much.

Comment: they need to make npm audit a beta feature until they fix its own issues at least with top 50 or something most used packages

Comment: Yeah it is real issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While those warnings [**can matter** for front-end apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57678904/14056591) and I suggest to check if they affect you, they're mainly designed for Node.js apps.

In the meantime, the co-author of Redux and `create-react-app`, Dan Abramov, explained these warnings here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174

**TLDR:** `npm audit` is broken for front-end tooling by design

`npm audit` is designed for Node apps so it flags issues that can occur when you run actual Node code in production. That is categorically not how Create React App works.

##### But I still see these warnings when creating a new project or running npm install

Yes, unfortunately that's how npm works since v6. You can [bring it up with npm](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/74578722/14056591). If enough people complain, maybe they'll rethink this decision. It is unfortunately actively hostile to build tooling.